# Office Add-in: EdgeHTML used when Edge with WebView2 should be

Tags: office-js, microsoft-edge, office-addins, webview2

I am developing Office add-ins for my company. I am testing on Microsoft Office 2021. Under Product Information on word, I see "Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021".

I have reviewed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#perpetual-versions-of-office-on-windows) and it seems clear that for Office 2021 the runtime selected should be Microsoft Edge with WebView2. However, my add-ins load with Microsoft Edge with Original Webview (EdgeHTML).

When going to "Security Info" for the add-in once it is loaded in the task pane, i see the runtime listed as "Microsoft Edge Legacy". Based on [this documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy-3e779e55-4c55-08e6-ecc8-2333768c0fb0), that means EdgeHTML.

Is this a mistake in the documentation? Is there some other configuration that is not listed here?

Note: Microsoft Edge with Webview2 is installed on my computer.

Comment: Could the document be WIP-protected? See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins#wip-protected-documents

Comment: Good question. The document is not WIP-protected.

Comment: In that case, if you haven't got an answer here in a couple more days, consider creating an issue at the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues).

Comment: It has been reported that updating Windows to the latest build makes WebView2 work. You can have a check.